# Entering text into textfield causing uipangesture object to move back to its orginal position

Tags: swift, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint, uipangesturerecognizer, sender

My swift code below has a image view connected to a pangesture. When something is entered into a textfield when after the image view is moved. The image view reverts back to its original position.The gif represents that what is going on. I just don't want the effect of the pangesutre to be nullified after text is entered into the textfield.

[image]
LINK TO GITHUB https://github.com/redrock34/sse

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var pic = UIImageView()
    let fight = (0..<10).map { _ in UIImageView() }
    var textEnter = UITextField()
    var g2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    var slider = UISlider()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fight[0].image  = UIImage(named: "a.png")

        fight.forEach{
            $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        [slider,textEnter].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)

            $0.backgroundColor = .blue
        }

        slider.backgroundColor = .clear

        g2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.g1Method))
        fight[0].addGestureRecognizer(g2)

        pic.backgroundColor = .clear
        pic.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        fight.forEach{
            $0.backgroundColor = .clear
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }            

        [pic].forEach{

            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false                
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([

            pic.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant :0),
            pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fight[0].bottomAnchor, constant : 0),

            pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.62, constant: 0),
            pic.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),

            textEnter.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant :0),
            textEnter.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant : 0),
            textEnter.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0),
            textEnter.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),

            fight[0].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant :0),
            fight[0].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textEnter.bottomAnchor, constant : 0),

            fight[0].heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            fight[0].widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            fight[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),

            slider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pic.bottomAnchor, constant : 0),

            slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08, constant: 0),
            slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),

        ])
        textEnter.textAlignment = .center

        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(pic)
    }

    @objc func g1Method(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        let tranistioon = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + tranistioon.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + tranistioon.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero,in: self.view)    }
}
```

Comment: I would use transform property to move around the components rather than applying the constraints directly and activating/deactivating them. Would be much more elegant.

Comment: How would I use the transform property inside of a uipangesture

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  You are saying that the textfield is already doing what you want, but you want to be able to move the image view also?  What 2 constraints are applied to the image view?  You want to be able to drag it just like the textview?  or something different?  please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix explicit frame setting with auto-layout constraints for the same object.

For example, if you:

- add a label to the main view
- set `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
- set constraints for the label

then, via code...

- change the `.center` property of the label

you will see the label move, but when the next UI update happens (you edit a text field, tap a button, rotate the device, etc), auto-layout will reset the frame of the label based on its constraints.

So, in your pan gesture handler, you can either update the `.constant` values for the `fight[0]` object (instead of changing its `.center`), or...

You can leave `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` for your `fight` objects and explicitly set their frames and centers.

Note: in either case, you do ***not*** want to constrain any other elements relative to the `fight` objects, or they will move when you move `fight[0]`.

Here is a modification to your `ViewController` class (from your GitHub zip), implementing the method of *not* using auto-layout constraints on your fight objects.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var pic = UIImageView()
    let fight = (0..<10).map { _ in UIImageView() }
    var textEnter = UITextField()
    var g2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    var slider = UISlider()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fight[0].image  = UIImage(named: "a.png")

        fight.forEach{
            $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        [slider,textEnter].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.backgroundColor = .blue
        }

        slider.backgroundColor = .clear

        g2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.g1Method))
        fight[0].addGestureRecognizer(g2)

        pic.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        fight.forEach{
            $0.backgroundColor = .clear
            view.addSubview($0)
            // do NOT use auto-layout for fight views
            //$0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        [pic].forEach{
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        // need a non-rendering "spacer" to vertically separate textEnter from Pic
        let spacer = UILayoutGuide()
        view.addLayoutGuide(spacer)

        // NOTE: do NOT constrain any elements relative to fight views

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([

            // constrain textEnter top / leading / trailing to view
            textEnter.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant : 0),
            textEnter.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),
            textEnter.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant :0),
            // constrain textEnter height to 0.1 * view height
            textEnter.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0),

            // constrain spacer top to bottom of textEnter
            spacer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textEnter.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // constrain spacer leading to view leading
            spacer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // constrain spacer height to 0.1 * view height
            spacer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10),
            // spacer width doesn't matter
            spacer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0),

            // constrain pic Top to spacer bottom
            pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacer.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // constrain pic leading / trailing to view
            pic.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),
            pic.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant :0),

            // constrain pic height as you had it
            pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.62, constant: 0),

            // slider constraints
            slider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pic.bottomAnchor, constant : 0),
            slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08, constant: 0),
            slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),

        ])

        textEnter.textAlignment = .center

        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(pic)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // set fight[0] frame *after* textEnter has been laid-out
        fight[0].frame.size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * 0.10, height: view.frame.height * 0.10)
        let x = view.frame.origin.x
        let y = textEnter.frame.origin.y + textEnter.frame.size.height
        fight[0].frame.origin = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }

    @objc func g1Method(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        let tranistioon = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + tranistioon.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + tranistioon.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero,in: self.view)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a class of UIImageVIew and write the following code:

```
import UIKit

class draggableImage:UIImageView {


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }



    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first;
        let location = touch?.location(in: self.superview);
        if(location != nil)
        {
        self.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location!.x-self.frame.size.width/2, y: location!.y-self.frame.size.height/2);
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }

}
```

Don't  forget to assign the class draggableImage to the Image View from the Attribute Menu.

Comment: what do I put in  var pic = draggableImage(coder: <#NSCoder#>) in the code part?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method instead

```
  var existingTransition : CGAffineTransform?
    @objc func g1Method(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        guard let child = sender.view else{return}
        let transitionPoint = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        let newTransition = CGAffineTransform(translationX: transitionPoint.x, y: transitionPoint.y)
        switch sender.state {
        case .ended,.cancelled:// on End
            if let existing = existingTransition{
                self.existingTransition = newTransition.concatenating(existing)
            }else{
                self.existingTransition = newTransition
            }
        default://on change and other states
            if let existing = existingTransition{
                child.transform = newTransition
                    .concatenating(existing)
            }else{
                child.transform = newTransition
            }
        }
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Sorry if my code is messy. But I checked some scenaios its working fine.

happy codding